# Enforce no bald pointers in C++

Tags: c++, coding-style, static-analysis

Generally speaking, in this crazy modern world full of smart pointers, I'm coming round to the fact that bald/bare pointers shouldn't be in method signatures.

I suppose there might be some cases where you need bald pointers for performance reasons but certainly I've always managed with references or references to smart pointers.

My question is this, can anyone suggest an automated way to enforce this? I can't see a way with clang, GCC or vera++

Comment: @PawełStawarz Look at the title. To HNJSlater : there is no option for that. Using bare pointers is not a bad thing on its own.

Comment: @Chnossos I focused so much on the question that I ignored the title. Yay me!

Comment: Mixing exceptions and manual lifetime management is easy to mess up and doesn't really offer any advantages over smart pointers (except maybe performance).

Comment: smart pointers are passed all too often. If your function is not going to modify lifetime (by storing the reference) it's better to pass a reference rather than a reference to a smart pointer. This way your function does not artificially restrict the caller's memory management model.

Comment: Yep that is certainly true, I even mention references in my original question. In my book references are fine, bald pointers not so much.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is ok for non-owning raw-pointers to be used in method signatures. It is **not** ok to use "[owning](http://herbsutter.com/elements-of-modern-c-style/)" raw-pointers.

For example this is quite ok:

```
void bar(const Widget* widget) {
  if (widget)
    widget->doSomething();
}

void foo() {
  Widget w;
  bar(&w);
}
```

If you want the `Widget` to be nullable you can't use a reference and using a smart pointer would be slower and not express the ownership model. The `Widget` can be guaranteed to be alive for the whole scope of `foo`. `bar` simply wants to "observe" it so a smart pointer is not needed. Another example where a non-owning raw-pointer is appropriate is something like:

```
class Node {
 private:
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> children_;  // Unique ownership of children
  Node* parent_;
 public:
  // ...
};
```

The `Node` "owns" its children and when a `Node` dies its children die with it. Providing encapsulation of `Node` hasn't been broken, a `Node` can guarantee its parent is alive (if it has one). So a non-owning raw-pointer is appropriate for a back reference to the parent. Using smart pointers where they are not required makes code harder to reason about, can result in memory leaks and is premature pessimization.

If smart pointers are used throughout instead, all kinds of things can go wrong:

```
// Bad!
class Node {
 private:
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>> children_; // Can't have unique ownership anymore
  std::shared_ptr<Node> parent_; // Cyclic reference!
 public:

  // Allow someone to take ownership of a child from its parent.
  std::shared_ptr<Node> getChild(size_t i) { return children_.at(i); }
  // ...
};
```

Some of these problems can be solved by using `weak_ptr` instead of `shared_ptr` but they still need to be used with care. A `weak_ptr` is a pointer that has the *option* of owning.

The point is to use the appropriate kind of pointer in the appropriate context and to have an ownership model that is as simple as possible.

And no, I don't think there is an automated way of enforcing this, it is part of the design. There are tricks you can use like Cheersandhth.-Alf said to try and enforce a particular class is used in the way you want by restricting access.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any automated tool to do this, but such a check wouldn't be too hard to implement in `cppcheck`, which is open source and AIUI offers an easy way to add new rules.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to completely stay away from raw (bald, bare) pointers even for function arguments. But it can sometimes be a good idea to make sure that all instances of a certain type are dynamic and owned by smart pointers. This involves two measures:

- Ensure (to the degree practical) that the type can only be instantiated dynamically.
- Ensure (to the degree practical) that instantiation yields a smart pointer.

The first point is easy: just make the destructor non-`public`, and voilá, the few remaining ways to instantiate that type non-dynamically are not very natural. Any simple attempt to declare a local or namespace scope variable will fail. As will simple attempts to use that type directly as a data member type:

```
#include <memory>

template< class Type >
void destroy( Type* p ) { delete p; }

class Dynamic
{
template< class Type > friend void destroy( Type* );
protected:
    virtual ~Dynamic() {}
};

//Dynamic x;  //! Nope.

struct Blah
{
    Dynamic x;      //! Nope, sort of.
};

auto main()
    -> int
{
    //Dynamic x;        //! Nope.
    new Blah;           //!Can't delete, but new is OK with MSVC 12...
}
```

Visual C++ 12.0 unfortunately accepts the above code as long as the out-commented statements remain out-commented. But it does issue a stern warning about its inability to generate a destructor.

So, `Dynamic` can only be created dynamically (without using low-level shenanigans, or ignoring that MSVC warning and accepting a memory leak), but how to ensure that every new instance is owned by a smart pointer?

Well you can restrict access to the constructors so that a factory function must be used. Another way to ensure use of the factory function is to define a placement allocation function, `operator new`, that an ordinary `new`-expression can't access. Since that's most esoteric and possibly non-trivial, and not of clear-cut value, the below code just restricts access to the constructors:

```
#include <memory>       // std::shared_ptr
#include <utility>      // std::forward

// A common "static" lifetime manager class that's easy to be-"friend".
struct Object
{
    template< class Type >
    static
    void destroy( Type* p ) { delete p; }

    template< class Type, class... Args>
    static
    auto create_shared( Args&&... args )
        -> std::shared_ptr<Type>
    {
        return std::shared_ptr<Type>(
            new Type( std::forward<Args>( args )... ),
            &destroy<Type>
            );
    }
};

class Smart
{
friend class Object;
protected:
    virtual ~Smart() {}
    Smart( int ) {}
};

//Smart x;  //! Nope.

struct Blah
{
    //Smart x;      //! Nope, sort of.
};

auto main()
    -> int
{
    //Smart x;        //! Nope.
    //new Blah;       //!Can't delete.
    //new Smart( 42 );       // Can't new.
    Object::create_shared<Smart>( 42 );      // OK, std::shared_ptr
}
```

One problem with this approach is that the standard library's `make_shared` doesn't support a custom deleter, and `shared_ptr` doesn't use the common deleter of `unique_ptr`. One may hope that perhaps this will be rectified in future standard.

---

Disclaimer: I just wrote this for this answer, it's not been extensively tested. But I did this in old times with C++98, then with a macro for the `create`-functionality. So the principle is known to be sound.

Comment: But that means I can't allocate on the stack, why would I want to enforce that?

Comment: @HNJSlater If you don't need owning pointers,  great! But one example where you do often need owning pointers is with polymorphic classes. Value semantics are not really appropriate for polymorphic classes and can result in things like object slicing. It is often safer to enforce that a polymorphic class can only be created by a factory and returned by smart pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this idea is that in the smart pointer world, `T*` is just a shorthand for `optional<T&>`. It no longer implies memory management, and as a result it becomes a safe idiom to identify an optional non-owned parameter.

Comment: An optional explicitly doesn't transfer ownership. A smart pointer explicitly transfers ownship (or shares it). A bald pointer may or may not transfer ownership. Because of this, I like optionals and smart pointers but I don't like bald pointers in boundaries. This doesn't feel like an answer to my question.

Comment: No, that's my point. In a smart pointer world, bald pointers do **NOT** transfer ownership.

Comment: But in a smart pointer world, why would you not use optional (or something similar)?